# How to assing values to 2 dimensional array with data from database in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

Suppose that Sql database is StudentInfo and Table name is Registration

```
ID----------Name---------------Email---------------------------PhoneNo
1           Munasunghe        amilamunasinghe@yahoo.com        0717069425    
2           Liyanarachchi     hareshliya6@gmail.com            0756706352
```

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "select ID, Name, Email, PhoneNo from Registration"; 
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query);
    DataTable dt1 = GetData(cmd1);
    int rowcount = dt1.Rows.Count;
    /* I want to assing dt1 datatable data to 2 dimensional array*/

}
```

The function GetData is used to get data from the Database.

```
 private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Please give an example code to help me.

Comment: How do you want the values stuffed in the array?
Are you looking for:
 arr[0][0] = 1
 arr[0][1] = "Munasunghe"
 arr[0][1] = "amilamunasinghe@yahoo.com"
 arr[1][0] = 2
 arr[1][1] = "Liyanarachchi"

Comment: If you want mixed datatypes, you'll probably need to create an object, if the datatypes can all be strings, this is easier to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
    object[,] Target = new object[dt1.Rows.Count, dt1.Columns.Count];


    int RowCount = 0;

    foreach(DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
        foreach(DataColumn dc in dt1.Columns)
        {

            Target[RowCount, dc.Ordinal] = dr[dc];
            RowCount++;
        }
```